# How to convert a type, loaded from one project, to an interface

Tags: vb.net, reflection

*Prerequisites*

- .NET environment
- A `Common` assembly with an interface `IModule`
- `Main` project, referencing `Common`
- `Implementor` project, referencing `Common`, but not referenced from `Main`
  When everything is built, the `Common.dll` is present in both `Main` and `Implementor`.

Now the `Main` project tries to load the class implementing `IModule` at runtime. What I could achieve so far:

```
Dim asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(asmFile)
For Each asmType in asm.GetExportedTypes()
    If asmType.IsClass AndAlso
       asmType.GetInterfaces().Any(Function(i) i.Name = GetType(IModule).Name) Then
        Dim handle = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(asmFile, asmType.FullName)
        Dim inst = CType(handle.Unwrap(), IModule) ' EXCEPTION
    End If
Next
```

So I can load the `Implementor` assembly and find the type implementing `IModule`. But I can't create an instance of it such that I can cast it to my local `IModule`. Is this at all possible?

*Workaround*

I found a workaround - in `Implementor` project, click on reference to `Common` and clear "Copy Local" flag. Then I can even use simpler code, like `IsAssignableFrom()`. But is this the only way? What if I get a DLL from third party, where the `IModule` is compiled into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**:
`Assembly.LoadFrom` loads the first found matching assembly in a directory tree (via the so called [Probing Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx)). So if you have your `Common` DLLin folder A and the updated `Common` DLL is in folder A\B then the one in folder A is taken (if both dlls have the same name).

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The load-from context allows an assembly to be loaded from a path not
>   included in probing, and yet allows dependencies on that path to be
>   found and loaded because the path information is maintained by the
>   context.
>
> The LoadFrom method has the following disadvantages.Consider using
>   Load instead.
>
> ```
> If an assembly with the same identity is already loaded, LoadFrom returns the loaded assembly even if a different path was specified.
>
> If an assembly is loaded with LoadFrom, and later an assembly in the load context attempts to load the same assembly by display name,
> ```
>
> the load attempt fails.This can occur when an assembly is
>   de-serialized.
>
> ```
> If an assembly is loaded with LoadFrom, and the probing path includes an assembly with the same identity but a different location,
> ```
>
> an InvalidCastException, MissingMethodException, or other unexpected
>   behavior can occur.

---

*Original Answer*:

Use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create the object and `typeof` to check if it implements the Interface :

```
Dim a As assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(asmFile)
Dim concreteModule As IModule = Nothing
For each type In a.GetExportedTypes().Where(Function(x) x.IsClass)
    Dim o  = Activator.CreateInstance(type)
    If TypeOf o Is IModule
       concreteModule = DirectCast(o, IModule)
       Exit For
    End If          
Next
```

Remark:

You wrote: `But I can't create an instance of it such that I can cast it to my local IModule`.
The concrete object must implement the Interface you cast to. I don´t know if I understood you correctly but casting from a Interface `IModule` in a 3rd party dll to a different Interface `IModule*` in your local dll will not work (unless your local interface implements the other).

Comment: `casting from a Interface IModule in a 3rd party dll to a different Interface IModule* in your local dll` - this is exactly what I want to do.

I give a DLL with `IModule` to a 3-rd party and get (at least) two DLLs back - the one with `IModule` and one with `Implemetor`. They are placed in a separated directory and loaded from there. But when loading, the local copy of `IModule` DLL is taken, while when I am trying to cast, main `IModule` is used (the one compiled with the `Main` project). Can I cast between these two?

Comment: I may found a partial workaround - using `ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom` and reacting on the "missing DLL" event by loading my `Main` DLL. I haven't tried it, but this should work when inspecting types. But when instantiating, I assume `ReflectionOnly` loading won't be enough, so I am in the same situation again.

Comment: Ok I guess I understood. Is the directory - where the modified 3rd party DLL are copied to - a subdirectory of your main project? If so can you change that? Imho .NET loads the first found matching assembly in a directory tree.

Comment: Yes, it is a subdirectory, and I can change that - but to what?

Comment: Any folder outside of your Main dll

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really follow you, why should I do that?

Comment: As I wrote before `Imho .NET loads the first found matching assembly in a directory tree`. So if you have your main dll in folder A and the updated main dll is in folder A\B then the one in folder A is taken (if both dlls have the same name).

Comment: I would suggest we start a chat if you have further questions

Comment: Okay, so you suggest basically the same as I did - strip the delivered `Common` DLL away, forcing .NET to load `Common` in my project, effectively replacing one type with the other. Then, I guess, there is no other solution (other than code generation for making a proxy).

Comment: Could you please make it an answer on its own, so I can mark it as an answer?

Comment: I wonder, though, how far this "duck typing" can go - I mean, replacing DLL with one type with another DLL, defining another type with the same name...

Comment: See my edit. I included some info about the probing path.